# PowerShell script to add computers to group that are not part of another group?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, automation, powershell-3.0

I am trying to pull together a PS script to automatically add computers to a security group that are not part of another group.

In this case, add all computers to group_b that are not part of group_a.

This is what I tried..

```
#get list of computers from group_a
$tpmobjects = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "group_a" | Select name
#add computers to group_b that are not in group_a
Get-ADComputer -Filter {SamAccountName -notlike $tpmobjects} | Foreach-Object { Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $_.SamAccountName -MemberOf "group_b" }
```

The error I get is...

```
Get-ADComputer : Type: 'System.Object[]' is not supported for extended attribute 'SamAccountName'.
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ADComputer -Filter {SamAccountName -notlike $tpmobjects}...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADComputer], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADComputer
```

Anyone have a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that `Get-ADGroupMember` returns multiple objects and the `-Filter` parameter doesn't support matching against multiple objects.

There are multiple ways around this, but the easiest is to simply filter the output from `Get-ADGroupMember` with `Where-Object`:

```
$Computers = Get-ADGroupMember group_a |Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'computer'}
```

You also don't need to wrap `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` in `ForEach-Object`, it accepts pipeline input, and an `ADComputer` object can be bound to the `-Identity` parameter directly without problems:

```
$Computers |Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -MemberOf group_a
```